Which Composite Limit Theorem to Trust?
I was reviewing Khan Academy's composite limit theorem and tried to cross reference it to other sources to understand it better. I understand it less now.
I found out that there is at least two different theorems and Khan Academy is either wrong or my understanding is wrong and I need help connecting the dots.
Khan's second "theorem" in particular I can't find any reference to it anywhere else so I don't know if I should trust it.
I need help to sort out which information I should trust.
Here are my findings:
"Universal" Composite Limit Theorem
I say "universal" because a quick google search will show this theorem on almost every site.
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c}g(x)=M\text{ exists}\text{ AND }\lim_{x\to M}f(x)=f(M)$
$\implies$
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c}f(g(x))=\lim_{x\to M}f(x)$
This version is cited by (theorem linked):
Oxford University
University of Connecticut
Proof Wiki (by simplification of disjunctive antecedents)
Study.com
Teaching Calculus
Khan Academy's (First) Theorem
This theorem is the same as above but a biconditional $\iff$ replaces the "if,then" $\implies$. It is cited here on Khan Academy.
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c}g(x)=M\text{ exists}\land\lim_{x\to M}f(x)=f(M)$
$\iff$
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c}f(g(x))=\lim_{x\to M}f(x)$
This theorem is more consequential but seems to be wrong given proof wiki's theorem below, as well as Khan's second theorem.
Proof Wiki's Theorem
This theorem is proven on proof wiki here. I believe the second OR statement is the formal version of Oxford's second theorem here.
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c}g(x)=M\text{ exists}\text{ AND }\lim_{x\to M}f(x)=f(M)$
$\text{OR }$
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c}g(x)=M\text{ exists}\text{ AND }\exists a,b:c\in(a,b)\forall d\in(a,b)(d\neq c\implies g(d)\neq M)$
$\implies$
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c}f(g(x))=\lim_{x\to M}f(x)$
This theorem seems to provide another path to conclude $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c}f(g(x))=\lim_{x\to M}f(x)$ when the first OR statement is false. This directly refutes Khan Academy's theorem.
Khan Academy's (Second) Theorem
This second theorem is provided as a method (here) rather than a theorem, and is thus not so rigorous.
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c^-}g(x)=M_1$ after an increasing/decreasing interval
$\text{ AND}$
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c^+}g(x)=M_2$ after an increasing/decreasing interval
$\text{ AND}$
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to M_1^\pm}f(x)=M$ ($\to M_1^-$ if interval was increasing, $\to M_1^+$ if interval was decreasing)
$\text{ AND}$
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to M_2^\pm}f(x)=M$ ($\to M_2^-$ if interval was increasing, $\to M_2^+$ if interval was decreasing)
$\implies$
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c}f(g(x))=M$, for some $M$

Khan's is wrong. For example, take $f(x) = 1$, $g(x) =1/ x$. Then $\lim_{x \rightarrow M} f(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(g(x)) = 1$ for ALL $c, M$. But clearly, $ \lim_{x \rightarrow c } g(x) = M$ for at most 1 value of $M$.

Might be worth notifying Khan Academy of the issue.
